# React / Как назначать классы по клику?

Tags: reactjs

Как в React назначать, переключать классы, по клику на кнопки?

```js
class AsideFilter extends React.Component {


    activeCorrectFilter = () => {


        let btnFilterLink = document.getElementsByClassName("bl_filter__link"),
            btnFilterLinkLength = btnFilterLink.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < btnFilterLinkLength; i++) {
            btnFilterLink[i].classList.remove("active");
        }

    };

    render() {
        return (


            <div className="bl_filter">
                <button className="btn_filter icon-filter" type="button">Filter</button>
                <ul className="bl_filter__full clearfix">
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} type="button" className="bl_filter__link active">Rock
                            News
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} type="button" className="bl_filter__link">Most
                            Popular
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} type="button" className="bl_filter__link">Top 21
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} type="button" className="bl_filter__link">Conserts
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        );
    }


};

ReactDOM.render(<AsideFilter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.bl_filter__link.active {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Как получить текущий индекс кнопки относительно родителя ненумерованого списка и добавить ей класс active, тем самым перекрасив её? (Или в Реакте это вообще всё по другому делается ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можно так.

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwm3l7l2nj)**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    var foo = document.querySelectorAll("button");

    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
      foo[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>3</button>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: А если необходимо, что бы все остальные кнопки при клике теряли класс .active ? *Я планирую данные кнопки использовать в качестве фильтровальных кнопок списка блога, по нажатию на которых должно происходить перестраивания метода вывода

Comment: @BlackStar1991, обновил. (ссылка та же)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Помогло

Comment: @BlackStar1991, не за что, желаю успехов!

Comment: Ойойой, что ж вы делаете то?)

Comment: Какой `document.querySelectorAll`, какой `classList.remove`, это же реакт!

Comment: Ответ [Dmitry Kozlov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217104/dmitry-kozlov) правильный

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, ответьте себе на вопрос: что такое Реакт? Дам подсказку: javascript, что вам мешает использовать ванильные конструкции js? Краткость - сестра таланта. Работаю с реактом уже больше 2х лет, ни разу казусов не было. Данные конструкции никоем образом не противоречат каким-либо "правилам".

Comment: К сожалению проблема есть, и количество лет опыта ни о чем не говорит. Что вы знаете про Virtual DOM и то каким образом работают приведенные мной функции?

Comment: _Данные конструкции никоем образом не противоречат каким-либо "правилам"_ - данные конструкции противоречат основополагающей концепции реакта. Вы правы в том что реакт это JavaScript, но с небольшой оговоркой: реакт это JavaScript работающий с Virtual DOM

Answer (score 2):

В стейте сохраняйте идентификатор нажатой кнопки. На кнопке проверяйте, является ли эта кнопка активной и добавляйте стиль

```js
class AsideFilter extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: ''
    }
   }

    activeCorrectFilter = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        active: event.target.id
      });
    };

    render() {
        return (


            <div className="bl_filter">
                <button className="btn_filter icon-filter" type="button">Filter</button>
                <ul className="bl_filter__full clearfix">
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button 
                          id="rockNews"
                          onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} 
                          type="button" 
                          className={"bl_filter__link " + (this.state.active === "rockNews" ? "active" : "")}
                        >
                            Rock News
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button 
                          id="mostPopular"
                          className={"bl_filter__link " + (this.state.active === "mostPopular" ? "active" : "")} 
                          type="button"
                          onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} 
                        >
                          Most Popular
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button 
                          id="top21"
                          onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} 
                          type="button" 
                          className={"bl_filter__link " + (this.state.active === "top21" ? "active" : "")}
                        >
                          Top 21
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li className="bl_filter__item">
                        <button 
                          id="concerts"
                          onClick={this.activeCorrectFilter} 
                          type="button" 
                          className={"bl_filter__link " + (this.state.active === "concerts" ? "active" : "")}
                        >
                          Conserts
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        );
    }


};

ReactDOM.render(<AsideFilter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.bl_filter__link.active {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так (у меня последняя версия реакта) -

```
import React, { Component, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';



const initialState = {
  first: '',
  second: '',
  third: ''
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if(action.type === 'first'){
    return {first: 'active', second: '', third: ''};
  }else if(action.type === 'second'){
    return {first: '', second: 'active', third: ''};
  }else if(action.type === 'third'){
    return {first: '', second: '', third: 'active'};
  }

  return state;
}

const App = ()=>{
  let [classes, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handler = type => ()=> dispatch({type});

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(classes);
  })

  return (
    <>
      <button className={classes.first} onClick={ handler('first') }>first</button>
      <button className={classes.second} onClick={ handler('second') }>second</button>
      <button className={classes.third} onClick={ handler('third') }>third</button>
    </>
  )
}


export default App;
```